# Copy shape key animation data to another object out of order (python)

Tags: python, scripting

I am trying to copy shape key animation data from on object to another. Each object shares the exact same shape key names, but they are in a different order. Also, the first frame of each object has a keyframe of zero set on all shapekeys. Any ideas? I have tried asking chatgpt to write a script but it returns an error, Python:
AttributeError: 'ShapeKey' object has no attribute 'animation_data'

import bpy

## Replace these with the names of your objects

source_object_name = "SourceObject"
destination_object_name = "DestinationObject"

## Get the objects

source_object = bpy.data.objects[source_object_name]
destination_object = bpy.data.objects[destination_object_name]

## Get the shape keys from the objects

source_shape_keys = source_object.data.shape_keys
destination_shape_keys = destination_object.data.shape_keys

## Create a dictionary of shape keys by name

source_shape_key_dict = {key.name: key for key in source_shape_keys.key_blocks}
destination_shape_key_dict = {key.name: key for key in destination_shape_keys.key_blocks}

## Copy the keyframes from the source shape keys to the destination shape keys

for source_key_name, source_key in source_shape_key_dict.items():
destination_key = destination_shape_key_dict.get(source_key_name)
if destination_key is not None:
destination_key.value = source_key.value
if source_key.animation_data is not None:
for source_keyframe in source_key.animation_data.action.fcurves:
destination_keyframe = destination_key.animation_data.action.fcurves.find(source_keyframe.data_path.replace(source_key.name, destination_key.name))
if destination_keyframe is not None:
for source_keyframe_point in source_keyframe.keyframe_points:
destination_keyframe_point = destination_keyframe.keyframe_points.insert(source_keyframe_point.co[0], source_keyframe_point.co[1])
destination_keyframe_point.interpolation = source_keyframe_point.interpolation

print("Shape key animation data copied successfully!")

.......
Sorry for the weird formatting, I copied the script from blender's text editor into the question.